# SVG Glyphs in HTML

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a few SVG glyphs whitch i need to draw with HTML.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Is it possible to create HTML with CSS so that it looks like the SVG?
My problem was the shadow at the arrows.

Comment: of course you can

Comment: Use z-index for the first and the fourth.

Comment: @Thomas Mueller see my answer

Comment: Just out of interest, why don't you simply embed the SVG shapes in-line?

Comment: @Boldewyn Because i have to set a text with different length into this elements and some text is too long so it overlaps, because svg elements don't make a line break at its own

Comment: Fair enough, text handling in SVG is hairy indeed. (Of course, you _could_ use HTML in SVG in HTML ;-) https://jsbin.com/tinejonami/edit?html,output )

Answer (score 2):

You could use `clip-path` for the arrows (and its shadow too) and pseudoelements with a `box-shadow` for the figure with the overlapped boxes

> [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XqgemJ)

---

**Markup**

```
<div class="arrow">Arrow</div>
<div class="boxes">Boxes</div>
```

**Css**

```
.arrow {
  height: 55px;
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 55px;
  padding: 0 35px;

}

.arrow::before, .arrow::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #666;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 25px 50%, 0% calc(100% - 5px), 85% calc(100% - 5px),  100% 50%, 85% 0);
}

.arrow::after {
  transform: translate(5px, 5px);
  opacity: .25; 
}



.boxes, .boxes::before, .boxes::after  {
  position: relative;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  border-color: #999;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-top-width: 2px; 
  border-right-width: 2px; 
  box-shadow: 3px 4px 0 #ccc;
}

.boxes::before, .boxes::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}

.boxes::after { top: -12px; left: 4px;   z-index: -1; }
.boxes::before { top: -20px; left: 14px;  z-index: -2; }
```

The other two figures can be obtained with the same approach (they are just a simple change of size and colours)

---

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This looks very good. The only problem is that it has to run in internet explorer too. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

here is one of shape:

```css
body{
padding:20px;
}
div {
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background: red;
    position:relative;
    padding: 9px;
    padding-right: 22px;
}

div:before {
    content: "";
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 17px 15px 17px 0px;
    border-color: transparent red transparent transparent;
    position: absolute;
    left: -15px;
    top: 1px;
}
div:after {
    content: "";
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 17px 15px 17px 0px;
    border-color: transparent white transparent transparent;
    position: absolute;
    left: 93px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle">Hello world </div>
```

Comment: I think the shadow under the arrow is a requirement